# Cannot find where a URI is being called with Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, inspect-element

In Google Chrome Inspect Element I am getting this error:

```
(index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://bb.bob.com/m/187/puerto-rico/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://bb.bob.com/member/jstorage/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

When I click on `(index):1` I get a full HTML page and it highlights (with an red x next to it):

```
<!doctype html>
```

I would have thought it would give me the JS where the call is being made.

1. Why is it giving me the page HTML?
2. How can I get the source of the URI call?

Comment: Try the Network tab in Chrome Inspector and filter by XJR. It might show you the culprit.

Comment: I am getting closer. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that usually caused by a external source, like a JS plugin from with an *http* URL, or even an image loaded directly from another website or something? Can't you just check all your source files for *http* (whole word only)?

Comment: @myfunkyside you are right. It was a redirect.